# R recipe packages - Remove outliers

Tags: r, outliers, recipe, data-preprocessing

Currently I write my master thesis and perform a data analysis with R. I decided to use the recipe package and to follow the approach of the following book: https://bradleyboehmke.github.io/HOML/.
In this book (precisely in Chapter 3.5), outlier removal is simply skipped. However, in every single paper I've read outlier removal is part of the preprocessing procedure. Now to my question:
Does the recipe package simply not provide a function to remove outliers or is it simply not necessary in case I perform a standardization and normalization of all numerical predictors?
Thanks in advance.